# Site is down after VM restart Google Cloud Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, instance

After a restart of my VM instances my site is down. I checked the IP address, but it didn't change. Do you have any ideas about what is wrong and how to fix it?

I run WordPress (Bitnami) on a Debian-based OS. I use Cloudflare CDN. I understand that on stopping a VM it doesn't keep the settings. Can I restore them?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! You’ll have to provide a much more detailed question to get a solution. What type of program are you running? From the sound of it I’d guess Wordpress or static HTML?

Comment: Yes I run Wordpress (Bitnami) Debian-based O.S I use Cloudflare CDN. I understand that on stopping a VN it doesn't keep the setting can I restore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your last error message

> Syntax OK (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not
> bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting
> down AH00015: Unable to open logs /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh
> : httpd could not be started Monitored apache

I have found similar errors due to Nginx, it could happen if you have it installed and it is creating conflicts. make sure you remove it as follow:

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common

sudo apt-get autoremove         #to remove unneeded dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

Your environment doesn't loose configuration "settings", but rather the servers that use those configurations will terminate their [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) when the VM shuts downs and will need to be restarted.

The problem is likely that you need to restart both your [Apache web server](https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/what-is-apache) *(which starts the PHP runtime and proxies HTTP requests)* and your [MySQL server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) *(which is your database)*...

Restart Apache:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Restart MySQL:

`sudo service mysql restart`
OR
`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

**EDIT:** It appears your [Bitnami image](https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress/) has a different [configuration](https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress/administration/control-services/)...

Start All services: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start`

Restart Apache: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Restart MySQL: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql`

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried to restart mysql and it said: Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Comment: It seemes that my port 80 is not open or already in use. I when I try to start apace I get the message:   

opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : apache not running Syntax OK (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started Monitored apache